# force the spark streaming's kafka consumer process to different machines

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I 'm using streaming integrated with streaming-kafka.

My kafka topic has 80 partitions, while my machines have 40 cores. I found that when the job is running, the kafka consumer processes are only deploy to 2 machines (40*2=80), the bandwidth of the 2 machines will be very very high.

I wonder is there any way to control the kafka consumer's dispatch, in order to balance the bandwidth and memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this consumer from Spark-Packages.

http://spark-packages.org/package/dibbhatt/kafka-spark-consumer

This consumer has been successfully running in many production deployment and this is most reliable Receiver based low level consumer.

This gives more control on offset commits and Receiver fault tolerant. This also give control of how many receiver you can configure for your topic which will determine the parallelism .

Dibyendu